# Disabling fields based off of multi picklist

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to disable/restrict fields when choosing a multi picklist value.

If (multi picklist) Applicable Reporting= No reporting required

Fields x,y,x should be disabled or read only when creating a record.

Can we do this without dynamic forms as my company does not have this right now. I tried validation rules but I couldn’t get it to trigger properly. I would also prefer no visual force as I am not a developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a validation rule to block editing or creating records that meet your requirements. Something like the below should block edits/creates when the result of the evaluation is true.

```
INCLUDES(Applicable_Reporting__C , "No reporting required")  &&  (ISCHANGED(X__C) || ISCHANGED(Y__C) || ISCHANGED(Z__C))
```